# Fixing an unsealed bathroom wall/floor gap

Tags: bathroom, leak

I had my bathroom gutted and renovated. The contractor installed the tile floor, put up the sheetrock walls and apparently left a gap between the floor perimeter and the wall. He then left the gap and put on the wood baseboard over it. I did not find out about this until I had a minor water overflow on the floor which went behind the baseboard and directly down to the basement. How do I fix this? Needless to say, there is also probably no seal under the tub but the wall tile is sealed and there's been no leaks from the tub.

Answer (score 2):

This is proper installation to account for thermal expansion and contraction of your floor surface. The "Joint Width" section of the TCNA Handbook says the following:

> Interior
>
> Perimeter joints at perimeter walls—not less than 1⁄4" and commonly covered by tile trim, cove base, or shoe molding.

For the typical size of a bathroom, filling that gap with a silicone caulk won't hurt anything as long as you can still get your wood trim installed nicely. If this is an unfinished basement, then I would rather have the water running down to the concrete floor than saturating my floor assembly.

Comment: This is a renovated living area bathroom in which any water spilled on the floor goes under the baseboard and flows down to the basement.

Comment: you can caulk the baseboard to the floor but generally baseboards exist to hide the gap between the floor and the wall.  if you spill water on the floor it goes to the basement is what generally happens.  your floors are not a shower pan.

Comment: If this is a proper installation then what is the point of installing a floor? Might as well put a piece of plywood on the beams put the tub sink and toilet on that and use the bathroom that way? Maybe put a pot on the basement floor so the water will flow into that if there is an accidental sink or tub overflow. Also when the water flows over the floor beams before it lands on the basement floor, won't the wood beams eventually rot?   You make no sense.

Comment: @John, I've amended the answer with the relevant information from EJ171 of the TCNA Handbook. Your contractor didn't screw up the perimeter of your tile job.

Comment: @John, when the water pours onto the wood framing, a substantial part runs off onto what I'm still assuming is a concrete floor to harmlessly evaporate. If the entirety of the water instead soaked into the floor assembly, then you'd have a bigger rot problem. Further, seeing the puddle on the concrete signals you to stop spilling water all over the place, whereas soaking into the floor assembly you might ignorantly continue spilling water all over the floor and ultimately damage it without any warning signals. Altering the tile job isn't the solution. Altering your behavior is the solution.

Comment: I apologize if I am being a pain but this is a finished tiled floor with sheetrock walls, tub, sink, and toilet and is a couple of years old. I accidentally had the shower head pointed outside the tub when I turned it on. Although I immediately turned it off the little water that did get on the floor, went behind the baseboard and directly down to the basement. Before the bathroom was renovated water leaking into the basement never happened with the old floor. That's why I believe the contractor screwed up, and that's why I was asking for help on how to fix this.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to go with the current answers, but that only means that the contractor who installed the last floor before the subsequent complete renovation of my bathroom is the best contractor in the world, but too late. I thought most contractors were good.

Comment: @John, if you want to "fix" this by plugging the leak, then fine. A recommendation for how to do that is already part of the answer. If the water drains to an unfinished basement, then it makes more sense to leave the leak as-is. This is already part of the answer, too. I understand that your pissed-level was probably at an 11 when you submitted your question, so maybe the "that installation is by-the-book" blinded you to the rest of the answer. I'm leaving the answer as-is.

Comment: Ok. I'll just caulk the baseboard and floor and see how that goes. I appreciate your responses. As far as calling a dozen contractors, I have no confidence in contractors anymore, especially the one that did my bathroom (there is another issue with his work which will have to deal with eventually, but that's the way it goes). I thought this was an important issue which is why I asked on this forum. Again, thanks for the responses.

Comment: Mr. Popham, I do not spill water "all over the place" This is the first time that enough water spilled to leak down to the basement floor (which is concrete) and is how I found out, and I do not "ignorantly" spill water all over the floor, but thanks anyway (without the insults).